# Proving $2(\sqrt{n} - 1) < \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt i}$

Tags: summation, induction

I'm trying to prove $$2(\sqrt{n} - 1) < \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt i}$$ (Which is the opposite pretty much of [Prove by induction that $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} \leq 2\sqrt{n} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992944/prove-by-induction-that-sum-i-1n-frac1-sqrti-leq-2-sqrtn-1))
And I'm encountering some troubles I fail to see through.

My attempt is by induction, and for $n=1$ it's clear, then if I assume for $k$ I get that for $k+1$:
$$2(\sqrt{k+1} - 1) < \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt i})$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt i}) > 2(\sqrt{k}-1)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$

Which would mean I would like to find that:
$$2(\sqrt{k}-1)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} - 2(\sqrt{k+1} - 1) > 0$$
But this is what I get:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}+2\sqrt{k}-2\sqrt{k+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}+2\frac{\left(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k+1}\right)\left(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}\right)}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}=$$
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}+2\frac{k-k-1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}=$$
$$ \frac{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}-2\sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}\left(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}\right)}<0)
 $$

So that is not true, how can I find that $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt i}) > 2(\sqrt{k+1} - 1)$ if what I get from my induction hypothesis doesn't help me since it's already smaller than what I'm searching for?

Comment: This is an instance of the well-known method of comparison series/integral, see here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Comment: @user10000100_u No it is not. (Did you try to follow your own advice? If you do, you are in for a surprise.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strengthen your inequality to $$\sum_{i=1}^n{1/\sqrt{i}} > 2(\sqrt{n+1}-1).$$ All you need to do for the induction step is to show $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} > 2(\sqrt{k+2}-\sqrt{k+1}).$$ Hint: $$RHS =\frac{2}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k+2}}.$$

Comment: Nice. Motto: If in trouble to mount an induction proof, look for a *stronger* inequality to show.

Comment: I'm looking at this and it seems pretty much like what I did, though obviously with \sqrt{n+1} instead of \sqrt{n}, but your induction step gave the elements \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k} in the reverse order compared to mine. Even knowing that I still can't find what I did wrong...

Comment: Your approach didn't work simply because the proposition is not strong enough to let one carry on the induction step.

Comment: Oh yeah I see it, I imagined the reversed order :P. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my answer if you find it helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another question, if you don't mind. What was the sign that the original inequality wasn't strong enough for the induction? Is me getting stuck there it or was there something else I need to notice?

Comment: Well, I was looking at the induction step and figured that in order to make it work I need a strengthened inequality and I backtracked and fixed the original inequality and checked the base case.

Answer (score 2):

This is just to illustrate a non-inductive method to proving the inequality:

\begin{align}\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}  &= 2\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{2\sqrt{i}} \\ & =2\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i} + \sqrt{i}} \\
&> 2\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1} + \sqrt{i}} \\
&= 2\sum_{i = 1}^n (\sqrt{i+1} - \sqrt{i})\\
&= 2[(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1}) + (\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}) + \cdots + (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})]\\
&= 2(\sqrt{n+1} - 1),
\end{align}

and $2(\sqrt{n+1} - 1) > 2(\sqrt{n} - 1)$.

Comment: I don't understand some of the steps actually, mainly the first (adding the square root of j to the denominator) and the last (going from the sum to n), but it looks pretty neat :)

Comment: I'll add some more steps for you. :)

Comment: Are you able to follow through with the steps now?

Comment: hmm, all clear now, though I'm still pretty sure I never would have figured it out myself. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach: since $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a differentiable and concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$,
$$\delta(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}&\text{if}&x\neq y\\ f'(x)&\text{if}&x=y\end{array}\right.$$
is a decreasing function with respect to both its parameters. This gives:
$$ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}=\delta(n,n)\geq \delta(n,n+1) = \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}, $$
so, summing both sides of the previous inequality for $n=1,2,\ldots,N$ we get:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq 2\left(\sqrt{N+1}-1\right) $$
as wanted.